# Access to module denied from within GAE dev server

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, permissions

I am developing an app for GAE.

Having installed the "feedparser" module with setuptools, I tried importing it (with "import feedparser") statement. However, the module does not load and when I look at the dev_appserver.py debug log on screen, I see the following:

```
Access to module file denied: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/feedparser-4.1-py2.6.egg/feedparser.py
```

So GAE dev server cannot access the module but I can't figure out why. The path is correct and the file is accessible.

I am fairly new to Python/Django/GAE - what am I missing?

Comment: BTW when I run the python commandline and try "import feedparser", it works without flaw

Comment: Sounds like a permissions error, what user is dev_appserver.py assuming when it runs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

App Engine runs Python code in a sandbox, and only authorized standard library modules & packages can be imported from your application.

as @mg has mentioned, if you want to allow for 3rd-party modules & packages, you need to bundle them with your application. to do that specifically for feedparser, just drop the `feedparser.py` file into your top-level App Engine directory (where your `app.yaml`, `index.yaml`, and `main.py` are located).

(UPDATED Oct 2011) also keep in mind the hard limits:

- max total number of files (app files and static files): 3,000 (upped to 10k in 1.5.5, Oct 2011)
- max size of an application or static file: 10MB (upped to 32MB in 1.5.5)
- max total size of all application and static files: 150MB

if you want to save on the total number of files, you can put a wad of `.py` files in a ZIP so you only pay for one file. although this article is slightly out-of-date -- recommending bundling of Django 1.0 which is now included -- the technique of bundling modules & packages into ZIP files still apply:

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django10_zipimport.html

Official page in the docs which discusses the file limitations:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python

(UPDATED Nov 2011): The link below features a list of whitelisted Python modules/packages with C code for 2.5. The Python 2.7 runtime frees up many restrictions so much so that the whitelist has become a blacklist. Here are the allowed/whitelisted 2.5 C modules as well as the disallowed/blacklisted 2.7 C modules:

http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/libraries.html

Answer (score 1):

Because in GAE you cannot access libraries that are not parts of GAE itself, are not included in GAE, like django 0.96.1, or are not part of your application. Install that library, and every one else, in the same path of your web application.

**EDIT**

From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python):

> You can include other pure Python
>   libraries with your application by
>   putting the code in your application
>   directory. If you make a symbolic link
>   to a module's directory in your
>   application directory, appcfg.py will
>   follow the link and include the module
>   in your app.
>
> The Python module include path
>   includes your application's root
>   directory (the directory containing
>   the app.yaml file). Modules you create
>   in your application's root directory
>   are available using a path from the
>   root. Don't forget to create
>   **init**.py files in sub-directories, so Python will recognize the
>   sub-directories as packages.